# How can we compute the mean curvature from the dual surface?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a compact connected closed smooth 2D surface $S$ in 3D space, then its dual surface is composed of all its tangent planes.
Specifically, given a point $\textbf p\in S$ and its unit normal  $\textbf n$, then its corresponding point on the dual surface is $[\textbf n, -\textbf n \cdot \textbf p]^T$.

For example, we have a surface $S:\textbf r(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$, and the corresponding unit normal is $\textbf n(u,v)$, then the dual surface is defined by $\textbf R(u,v,\lambda)=(\lambda \textbf n(u,v),-\lambda \textbf n(u,v)\cdot\textbf r(u,v))$.
The dual surface have the property that its normal at $(u,v,\lambda)$ is exactly $(\textbf r(u,v),1)$.
And the question is: can we get the mean curvature at $\textbf r(u,v)$ when only the dual surface is known?

Comment: Could you provide more details on what the dual space is? Perhaps you mean that the corresponding point is $$ \frac{n}{n\cdot p}?$$

Comment: @Deane : Actually, the dual surface is in a 4D space. Basicly, we can character a plane using its normal vector and the distance to the origin, making it a 4D vector. So, all the tangent planes form a 2D surface in a 4D space.

Comment: I'm curious about where this arises. Do you have a reference I could glance at?

Comment: For a surface in 4-space, the mean curvature is not a scalar but a vector-valued function on the surface. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, the dual surface is in $\Bbb RP^3$, not in $4$-space. Since the surface is in fact orientable, you can view the dual surface in $S^3$.

Comment: Ah. And if you use affine coordinates, you get the surface I suggested. @TedShifrin, thanks for the clarification. But I’ve never seen this before. Where is it discussed?

Comment: @Deane: I know it from classical projective algebraic geometry (dual curve, dual hypersurface). I've never seen it before in the real context. The question is a weird mix of Riemannian and projective (where some things no longer have meaning). I too am curious where the OP got this ... I guess we want to recover the Gauss map (and the trace of its derivative), but — just knowing the dual surface — it's not obvious.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks. My reaction was similar, that it's used in complex projective geometry but I'd never seen it in a real projective setting. But now I recognize it as something that's also seen in convex geometry.

Comment: @Deane : It arises from my learning process in dual surface, just a curious question.

Comment: Where are you learning it from?

Comment: @Deane : I learn it from the literature [link](http://perso.lcpc.fr/tarel.jean-philippe/brown/jpt-iccv01.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TedShifrin's comment, I can provide a possible answer to your question.

Let me set things up in more detail. $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$ Let $S \subset \R^3$ be a surface and, for each $p \in S^2$, $n(p) \in S^2$ be the unit normal, where $S^2$ denotes the unit sphere. This is also known as the Gauss map.

Consider the map
\begin{align*}
\Phi: S &\rightarrow \R P^3\\
p &\mapsto [ n(p), n\cdot p ]
\end{align*}
If you assume $n\cdot p \ne 0$, then you get a map
\begin{align*}
\phi: S &\rightarrow \R^3\\
p &\mapsto [ n(p), n\cdot p ] = \left[ \frac{n}{n\cdot p}, 1\right].
\end{align*}
If this map has maximal rank, then you get an immersed surface in $\R^3$, which I'll call $S^*$. If $S$ is the boundary of a convex body containing the origin (like the unit ball of a norm), then $S^*$ is the boundary of the polar convex body (unit ball of the dual or operator norm). I'm going to assume, perhaps wrongly, that you want the mean curvature of this surface.

Here's the basic fact: If you assume that the Gauss curvature of $S$ is nonzero, then the second fundamental form of $S$ is invertible. In that case, the second fundamental form of $S^*$ at each $\phi(p)$ is the inverse of the second fundamental form of $S$ at $p$. Using this, the mean curvature of $S$ at $p$ is given by
$$
H(p) = \operatorname{tr} A^{-1}(\phi(p)),
$$
where $A(n)$ is the second fundamental form of $S^*$ at $n \in S^*$.

It's worth noting that, when $S$ is a closed convex surface, so is $S^*$ and the function $n \mapsto n\cdot p$ is called the support function of $S$.

Comment: Thanks! But the mean curvature we want is on the original surface. I edited my question in more detail.

Comment: So the dual surface is not a surface but a 3-dimensional hypersurface. It is possible to find a formula for the second fundamental form of the $3$-dimensional surface in terms of the original surface, but the formula for the mean curvature depends not only on the inverse of the second fundamental form of the original surface but also on $|p|$ (I believe).